# How to show character matrix in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a list such as `{ {1 ,1 }, "Q"}, { {2 ,3 }, "E"}, { {3 ,5 }, "Q"}, { {4 ,2 }, "Q"}, { {5 ,4 }, "Q"}, { {1 ,5 }, "E"}`, and I need to show the characters in a rectangular grid, for example, in this case, `5*5` grid, such that on `(1, 1)`, there is a char `Q`, on `(2, 3)` there is a letter `Q`, ..., and on `(1, 5)` there is a letter `E`. And all the remaining positions in the grid is shown as blank.

Please help me.

Comment: There's a new [mathematica.se] only site that you may be interested in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html) is set up to do this.  This also uses `@@@` which is short for [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) at level 1:

```
dat =
{{{1, 1}, "Q"},
 {{2, 3}, "E"},
 {{3, 5}, "Q"},
 {{4, 2}, "Q"},
 {{5, 4}, "Q"},
 {{1, 5}, "E"}};

SparseArray[Rule @@@ dat, {5, 5}, ""] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The second argument of `SparseArray` (here `{5, 5}`) is the explicit array size.  You can use `Automatic` to have it sized to the farthest point of your data.  The third (optional) argument is the expression to use as the "background" of the array.  Here I use an empty string `""` to meet your request for "blank."  Since this becomes hard to read you may prefer grid lines:

```
Grid[
 SparseArray[Rule @@@ dat, {5, 5}, ""],
 Frame -> All
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I want to get rid of 0 in the matrix! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Mr Wizard answer is the optimal one. But just for fun, here is a slightly different way to do using pure function

```
Grid[SparseArray[ #[[1]] -> #[[2]] & /@ dat, {5, 5}, ""], Frame -> All]
```